# React click handler not working and writing on="[object Object]" into DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**UPDATE:** This turned out to be a Babel configuration issue in the end.

I'm working with React function components for the first time and am getting some unexpected results with event handlers. Here's a massively reduced test case I created after encountering problems with a more fleshed-out component:

```js
const App = () => {

  const handler = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    console.log('handleAppClick');
  };
  
  return (
    <div onClick={ handler }>This is the whole thing.</div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

#app {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.12.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.12.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

It's my expectation/understanding that there is no binding necessary in this case because there's no need for a `this` reference in the handler. I've tried defining the handler inside and outside `App`, defining it as an arrow function, defining it as simply `function handler(e) { ... }`, but in all cases, I don't get a working click handler on this div on the rendered page, and if I inspect the DOM I can see a `on="[object Object]"` attribute on the div.

What's going on here? Seems like I'm just missing something glaringly obvious here.

Comment: I have no idea why your example wouldn't work, everything looks correct to me.  Maybe try inlining the onClick function and see if it fires that way first and then go from there?

Comment: I have updated your question to include a runnable snippet rather than a static one. As you can see, that's working as expected, so I think you over-simplified your code. Could you please add something that resembles the original code?

Comment: code works fine

Comment: @Danziger Well, I didn't over-simplify the JS I posted — the code I posted is a straight copy-paste from the project that was exhibiting the problem. I'm using a pretty straightforward Webpack build, and a totally minimal main.js file to render the app component. I wonder if there's something wrong with the build that could be contributing to this? No errors or warnings in the terminal and no issues in the browser console either.

Comment: Yes, if that's the original code, then I doubt the issues is there. Check that Webpack config and if you can't make it work maybe post that too.

Comment: This code works for me ? maybe add some more info  >

Comment: This turned out to be a Babel configuration issue in the end. Thanks to all who commented or made suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a Babel configuration issue in the end. Thanks to all who commented or made suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

i think you have to call the handler not reference it
`<div onClick={ handler() }>This is the whole thing.</div>` ----> also try
`<div onClick={ (e) => handler(e) }>This is the whole thing.</div>`